# Posting notification halts the further execution of code

Tags: ios, swift

I have a singleton object for observing Network status, it's based around NWPathMonitor class.

In the `pathUpdateHandler` callback I want to post a custom notification with current interface type of the path and then the strangest thing happens: I have place breakpoints before and after the .post method and the second breakpoint is never reached and the notification does is not posted. What could be the issue? It's the first time I've encountered such situation

```
    class NetworkMonitor {

static let shared = NetworkMonitor()

        private let monitor: NWPathMonitor

        enum InterfaceType: String {
            case wifi
            case cellular
            case other
            case none
        }

        private init() {
            monitor = NWPathMonitor()
            monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
                print("Before notification")

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NetworkMonitor.connectionChangedNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["interface": path.interfaceType])

                print("Notification posted") // This line is not being printed
            }
        }

        public func start() {
            let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
            monitor.start(queue: queue)
        }
    }

    fileprivate extension NWPath {
        var interfaceType: NetworkMonitor.InterfaceType {
            guard status == .satisfied else {
                return .none
            }
            if usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
                return .wifi
            } else if usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
                return .cellular
            } else {
                return .other
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I have subscribed to this notification in two places, A and B. I noticed that the callback in object B gets called twice and in A not one time. I have no idea what is going on here, for now I have commented out the code in B and everything is working properly, but I mean, what the heck.

In both objects I have

```
var connectionObserver: Any?

connectionObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: 
NetworkMonitor.connectionChangedNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
...
}
```

If I don't use the connectionObserver variable the bug also exists

Changing the `rawValue` of notification name does not change anything

Comment: who catches the notification? I am not sure about post implementation but if post immediately notifies observers then one of them might cause this problem

Comment: Actually this is not a singleton

Comment: It is, I have updated the code

Comment: what does the block in object B do when he catches the notification?